# Rails API .permit() is not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller and utilizing the require and permit methods to control what can be submitted to the API.  Not sure when or what I changed but now the API is allowing all params to be excepted.  I have looked through source control and don't see anything that really jumps out at me why it would now allow all params.

**Controller:**
[Project Controller](https://gist.github.com/jonathanread/07a18975bc5e61dcb054f6a1c3e7ac3d)

**Model:**
[Project Model](https://gist.github.com/jonathanread/68021a19e216bf90718d7b8ffa4190f8)

The API controller is now allowing below, even though ':blah' is not a white listed param.

```
{"project_id":2,"location_id": 2,"blah":"blah"}
```

Any help would be great! Is there some global setting or anything? If you need more info. let me know

Comment: How do you access the parameters? With `params` or with `project_params`? Only the second method is restricted to the whitelisted parameters.

Comment: I am using all the built in features of rails passing the project_params into the Project.new, as shown in the Gist.  This is allowing non-white listed parameters and I can't figure out why. It is doing this for all my controllers in the rails project not just this controller.

Comment: Can you post the full parameters hash?

Comment: @mysmallidea I already included the json i am posting to my controller so  I am not clear what your asking for.

Comment: Actually what would be most helpful is the full log for this request. It would look something like `Started PATCH "/project/123"...` all the way down to `Completed 302 Found in 7ms`

Comment: Before I do that am I understanding the functionality correctly: If I pass a parameter in my JSON that is not on the white list I should receive an error?

Comment: No you won't receive an error, that parameter will simply be ignored.

Comment: If you check your logs like @mysmallidea stated, you should see a warning about unpermitted params. Non-white listed params are simply ignored, whereas `require` will raise `ActionController::ParameterMissing` if the required key is missing.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the clarification.  Looks like it was a misunderstanding on my part how the .permit() feature works.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @mmicheal in the comments rails will not return an error when non-permitted params are sent to the controller, they are simply ignored. If you suspect that there is a params problem review the log files.